# ESRI Feature Service - Unable to complete operation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, network-analyst, feature-service

I have a road network published on ArcGIS Portal 10.6. I created it using ArcMap 10.6.

While publishing I enabled the network service and later I changed the service properties to include the feature access and allowed the update operation.

When I try updating attributes of a feature in roads layer it is not updating. I checked the network tab in Developers tool and i noticed the *update operation* is giving the following response

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Internal error during object update."]}}
```

Can I edit a layer once it is part of road network and is published?

**Update:**

I checked the ArcGIS Server logs after trying the edit function and it gave me the following error. I only edited roads layer but looks like it is trying to edit barriers as well.

```
SEVERE  An error occurred.  RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Error: Insufficient permissions [ND_14394_DirtyAreas][STATE_ID = 393].  RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Initialization of Layer: Polygon Barriers failed.   RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Layer: Polygon Barriers does not use SDE GeoDatabase. Feature Access capabilty requires the data to be on SDE GeoDatabase.  RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Initialization of Layer: Line Barriers failed.  RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Layer: Line Barriers does not use SDE GeoDatabase. Feature Access capabilty requires the data to be on SDE GeoDatabase. RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Initialization of Layer: Routes failed. RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Layer: Routes does not use SDE GeoDatabase. Feature Access capabilty requires the data to be on SDE GeoDatabase.    RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Initialization of Layer: Point Barriers failed. RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Layer: Point Barriers does not use SDE GeoDatabase. Feature Access capabilty requires the data to be on SDE GeoDatabase.    RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Initialization of Layer: Stops failed.  RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  Layer: Stops does not use SDE GeoDatabase. Feature Access capabilty requires the data to be on SDE GeoDatabase. RoadNetwork.MapServer
SEVERE  This exception was thrown after the response was committed. Access to this resource is not allowed  Rest
SEVERE  Response already committed. Cannot forward to error page.   Rest
SEVERE  Response already committed. Cannot forward to error page.   Rest
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is check the ArcGIS Server logs, it usually has more detailed information about these kind of errors. (You may have to set the loglevel to Verbose or Debug first)